# Is saying "herbal tisane" redundant?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

In a novel I am reading a character says,

> I could fix you some herbal tisane.

Is this redundant? (And to be picky, does one 'fix' tea?)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Yes, one fixes tea, strange as it sounds. "Make" is probably more common in the US. Is it redundant? I think that will be primarily opinion based. Have you ever heard of meat tea? (I've heard of manure tea, but only plants drink it.) Since you're here, please have a look at the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on how to use this site. Again, welcome!

Comment: 'Make' is more common in the UK also, as is 'brew'. 'Mash' might even be so too.

Comment: Talk about picky! Of course you can fix tea, why not? I don't know what you're referring to being redundant.

Comment: @Prismonic The question of redundancy is about *herbal tisane:* is tisane always herbal? If so, the adjective is redundant.

Comment: Not all the plants used for tisanes are herbs (at least not in common parlance). At work we often drink a cinnamon-ginger-liquorice tisane, none of which I would normally call ‘herbs’. _Tisane_ is also an alternative spelling of the far more obscure word _ptisan_, which is a different drink, usually cereal-based.

Comment: One would be tempted to suspect that the story is translated from another language, and thus the more idiomatic "herbal tea" got mistranslated.  (Though [herbal tisane](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22herbal%20tisane%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) does get quite a few hits in Google Books.)

Answer (score 1):

When you write your novel, you can be more succinct.  I suspect this author slightly misunderstood *tisane*, or was concerned the reader might not understand it.

Hard to be sure without some context, but if I were going to nitpick (and I do like to nitpick too), I might be annoyed about *tisane* and *fix* not matching stylistically very well.  I suppose you might be right that *herbal tisane* is rather like *potato latkes*.  But *herbal tisane* doesn't bother me as much as it bothers you, and it doesn't bother me as much as the *latkes* example.  We are in a pretty subjective realm with these criticisms.

I think *fix* may be more common in the South of the United States than in some other places.

Comment: Jews made pancakes for Hanukkah [before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potato_pancake#Jewish_latke) potatoes were brought back from the New World. So even *potato latkes* isn't entirely redundant.

Comment: @PeterShor - Your wikipedia article led me to http://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2015/12/the-great-latke-lie/420018/.  Live and learn!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a mashup of *herbal tea* and *tisane*. So, strictly speaking, it is redundant.

> Herbal tea, or, more properly, tisane (UK /tɪˈzɑːn/, US /tɪˈzæn/), is any beverage made from the infusion or decoction of herbs, spices, or other plant material in hot water, and usually does not contain caffeine. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herbal_tea)

Comment: What I thought was a simple question has been shown from the helpful replies to have been far from simple. I gained much from them.